# Opening a text file from a command line argument

Tags: c++, text-files, command-line-arguments, ifstream

I am trying to open a file from a command line argument.

I've debugged my program:

when I print the value of file it gives the value < incomplete type>.

when I print the value of argv it gives the value (char **) 0x7fffffffe4e0.

when I print the value of argv[1] it gives the value 0x0.

The function won't open my file. Not sure why?

I've tried:

`if (file.is_open())` too and same problem.

In my main function I pass:

```
buildBST(&argv[1]);

BSTTreeData buildBST (char *argv[]){
  vector <string> allwords;

  BSTTreeData Data;
  BinarySearchTree<string> Tree;

  ifstream file (argv[1]);

  char token;

  string listofchars = "";
  string input;

  int distinct = 0;
  int line = 1;

  if (file){
      //if the file opens
      while (getline(file, input)) //gets every line in the file
      {
          for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) //gets all the contents in the line
          {
              token = input[i]; //each character become a 'token'
              if (isalpha(token))
              {
                  //if the character is an alphabetical character
                  listofchars += token; //append character to a string
                  if (Contains(allwords, listofchars) == false)
                  {
                  //if the current word has not already been added to vector of words
                      //increment the distinct word count
                      distinct += 1;
                      Tree.insert(listofchars); //creates the BST
                      allwords.push_back(listofchars); 
                      //add current word to vector of all the words
                  }
                  else
                  line++; //increments the line number
              }
              else
                  line++; //increments the line number
          }
          listofchars = ""; //creates empty character string
      }
    }
    file.close(); //closes file

    Data.BST = Tree;
    Data.linenumber = line;
    Data.distinctwords = distinct;
    Data.words = allwords;
    return Data;
}
```

Comment: If `argv[1]` is `NULL` then the problem lies in the fact that you are not passing the file name as the first argument.  How are you running the program?

Comment: I compile using 'g++ -g -std=c++11 myfile.cpp' and execute './a.out test.txt'

Comment: Wait, you passed `&argv[1]` to `buildBST`, so that means the `argv` parameter in `buildBST` now points to the *first argument*.  This means `argv[1]` inside `buildBST` refers to the *second argument*, not the first!  (Remember that indices in C are *zero-based*.)

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So what your saying is that in my main I should pass argv[0] to buildBST? and also changing 'ifstream file (argv[0]);'?

Comment: `arg[0]` usually contains the path to the application not the first argument passed to it (i.e. `/bin/appname`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that in most operating systems, `argv` in the `main` function is an array of the form:

```
argv[0]        = /* path to the program ("zeroth argument") */;
argv[1]        = /* first argument */;
argv[2]        = /* second argument */;
...
argv[argc - 1] = /* last argument */;
argv[argc]     = NULL;
```

The problem here is that you're looking at the *second* argument, not the first.  When you call `buildBST(&argv[1])` in the `main` function, you shift the pointer by one element, so that *within* `buildBST` the `argv` now points to the first argument rather than the zeroth argument, and hence the expression `argv[1]` within `buildBST` yields the second argument rather than the first.

The solution is to either:

1. pass `&argv[0]` (or equivalently, just `argv`) into `buildBST` and then get the argument using `argv[1]`, or
2. pass `&argv[1]` (or equivalently, `argv + 1`) into `buildBST` and then get the argument using `argv[0]`.

The first approach is probably more readable since you're not altering the meaning of `argv`.

Comment: I'd argue that the second approach is best, since you can then re-use the code simply by passing, for instance, argv[2] into the function. Of course, I wouldn't pass an array in either, just pointers to the strings.

Comment: You can also do that, but as you said in that case you should not pass in a `char **` to begin with and certainly not label the variable `argv`.

Comment: After I do this, I get a "Control may reach end of non-void function" error

Comment: Did you forget to put `return XXX;` somewhere?